# PayPal - Third party form encryption

Tags: php, forms, encryption, paypal

I am developing a third party PayPal form for a website, and I need encryption.
I am not just simply using buttons, there is a form where people fill out how many of each item they need, and then they can press one button to add them all.
So far, I have gotten to the point where I can order the items, but I can just go into the site's code and change any of the prices that I want to any price I want and just place the order.

Another thing is, how can I allow someone to order ZERO of something while ordering something else, becaise whenever I submit 0, PayPal says it must be an "integer greater than or equal to 1"?

#### Here is the screenshot of my PayPal order form:

[Screenshot of my third-party PayPal order form http://www.drumtee.com/images/form_screen.png](http://www.drumtee.com/images/form_screen.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you as the web designer should have access to the site code.  HTTP is a readonly server to browser transmission mechanism, so people can't change your code.

If an item count is 0, then just don't send that item to PayPal, it makes sense that they are not really interested in things that you are not selling.

Comment: yes, but in the browser F12 tools, you can temporarily change the price, hit submit, and it will say the price you wrote on PayPal order summary.

Comment: Ummm... You are doing something very wrong.  The price should be calculated in a JavaScript variable as you transfer AND **SANITIZE** the information from the screen and format it for PayPal **AFTER** you hit sumbit.  You shouldn't just take the properties from the HTML elements.